# Allow Python to access the page that is displayed on Google Chrome?

Tags: python

I heard the google terms of service does not allow automated scraping for the search results, and the API is pretty slow, so I thought I might try something like

1. Manually enter a search item
2. Have the Python script get all URLs from the google search page and analyze them, something like

```
def onPageLoad():
    # get python to read the HTML of the current open tab
    first_res = select_first_result_from_browser()
    if not certain_criteria(first_res):
        do_something()
    else:
        do_something_else()
```

Is this possible (if it does not violate the terms of service)?

Comment: You can use selenium to have Python actually create and control a browser process, then Beautifulsoup could parse data from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `playwright`. Playwright is a python library for web browser automation, so you can scrape web pages and get information from them. Here's an example of code:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, channel="chrome")
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://example.com') #go to whatever site you want
    element = page.locator('you can use css or xpath to locate an element in html')
    element.get_attribute('something') 
    browser.close()
```

This code would launch a chrome browser, and allow you to search google (by heading to whatever the google search urls are). Note that I passed the argument `headless=False`, so that you can see the browser open when you're testing (you could do away with the argument if desired). Of course, you'll need to learn a little bit of html, but it's pretty straightforward. Installation and use are all covered in the *very clear and informative* [documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro).

Comment: I ended up doing that manually instead since I needed to verify the result myself anyways, but I was looking for something like this. Thanks!